# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "login" at path \"_id\" for model "users"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model called `users` and I have a login API for the authentication. The API was working fine, but now when I made a request to the login API, I am getting this error

```js
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"login\" at path \"_id\" for model \"users\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"login\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "login",
    "path": "_id"
}
```

I have tried in my Postman and also in my app. Same issue I am getting.

Steps I tried:

1. I removed all the code in login API and console logged the `req.body`. Even then, I am getting the same issue.
2. I cleared all the data from the database and started from the beginning and even then getting the same issue.
3. I also deleted the login API and made a request to it. Ideally, it should return 'Cannot POST', but I am getting the same issue.

Mongoose version: 5.1.4

Answer (score 0):

This cast type error occurs when the parameters you pass simply cannot be converted to Mongoose ObjectID. So from the littel your provided here, It would seem that value "login" somehow gets to the mongoose model and it tries to convert it to a Mongo Object ID which should obviously fail.

Post the code for further investigation of the error